# How do I detect if a UIView is present or not for a given class size?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I want to build an app that works similar to SplitViewController but without using SplitViewController. When the app runs in iPad, two view much show up simultaneously. Master and Detail. 
When the app runs in an iPhone, only Master view will show up and when a user taps on an item the detail view will show up.

I looked at Master Detail sample project provided by xcode. This sample project uses multiple storyboards. 1 for iPad and another for iPhone. I one to use single storyboard.

What can I use achieve this type of UI?

So far, I am able to setup class sizes so that when running in regular x regular, two container view shows and and the container view on the left loads the master view controller and the container view on the right loads the detail view controller.

When the phone runs on iPhone, it only loads the master view controller and when I tap on an item on the master view controller, it segues into Detail view controller.

The problem now is, when on an iPad, if I tap on an item in master view controller, instead of loading the data in the detail view controller on the right, it opens a new view controller and completely covers master view controller.

I am not expecting a complete solution to this problem. Just a guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a storyboard for each UI style. There's a reason they used multiple storyboards, after all...

Comment: Size Classes. Wasn't Size class introduced so that we don't use multiple storyboards? Also in xcode 6, when you select "Universal" for Devices, you cannot select storyboard files like you could in xcode 5 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a similarly structured app. I am handling all of my segues and ViewController changes programmatically. to check to see what type of device you are on, to know which type of changes to make, run this code:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //iPad Implementation
    <#statements#>
}
else{   //iPhone Implementation
    <#statements#>
}
```

I use it so much I actually added this into my code snippet library.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test this out. If you don't mind me asking, Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: When I first learned to program universal apps, this is how I was taught. The only way I can think of doing this differently would be using multiple storyboards like @Ian MacDonald mentioned and doing your transitions through IB. I feel like I have more control doing it in code so I would recommend using the if statement. Though, this can add a lot of code if you have need of doing things differently for each version, which my app does. Almost every single function has one of these statements in it.

Comment: True. I can see my app having alot of if else statements like this. I honestly don't like the dependency. I also don't want to have repetitive code for ipad and iphone. Having multiple storyboard still means I'll have multiple code. The only difference would be, the code would be separated in 2 viewController files instead of one.

Comment: The way I have this implemented is, I have 3 view controllers. One is the base, that hold the other two. In iPad i load both view controllers together and on iPhone I load one and using your code, I am planning on either, segueing into the third controller, or using notification to update the third controller. Second and Third view controller does not communicate to each other directly. Second and third view controller delegates to the main view controller, which tells second and third view controller what to do. Does this look like a good implementation?

Comment: Sounds similar to what I'm doing. Lots of nsnotifications to update things.